# libgdx tiledmap rendering optimazation

Tags: libgdx

I'm new to game development can anyone show me how to render tiles which were only seen by the camera I cant seem to find straight answer in google.

The game is in 2D and im using tiled

Comment: What have you already tried etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer or another renderer that inherits from BatchTileMapRenderer, then you should be calling setView before rendering the map. There are two overloads of setView

```
@Override
public void setView (OrthographicCamera camera) {
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    float width = camera.viewportWidth * camera.zoom;
    float height = camera.viewportHeight * camera.zoom;
    viewBounds.set(camera.position.x - width / 2, camera.position.y - height / 2, width, height);
}

@Override
public void setView (Matrix4 projection, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(projection);
    viewBounds.set(x, y, width, height);
}
```

You'll notice that each version sets a viewBounds, which is a rectangle. Any tiles outside of this rectangle will not be rendered. In other words, the first overload of setView is already doing this calculation for you. However, if you want fine control over this viewbounds rectangle, you can use the second overload.

Comment: I didn't know it was already doing the job, what a noob I am sorry, Thanks again guys

Comment: No worries. It's hard to know if a tile is being rendered outside a camera :). Please remember to mark an answer if you are satisfied with one of the answers on your post.

Comment: I'm not sure how you draw your tiles but if you are just looping your array and draw the tiles they are being rendered outside the screen. You should alter the double for loop for `X` and `Y` so it just renders within the viewBounds. It's simple if you think about it, you know camera position, width and height and you know tile size. Calculate how many tiles need to be rendered horizontal and vertical and create the loops for that.

Comment: @Menno - As I stated, my answer only applies if you use  a TiledMapRenderer supplied by libgdx. The renderer checks against the viewbounds. If you are manually drawing then you have to check the camera yourself

Answer (score 0):

So you will need a normal orthographic camera and an orthogonal tiled map renderer (assuming you are using square tiles) then you set the view of the tiled map renderer to the camera and call the tiled map renderer to render

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps

Comment: thank you for the response, This is what i currently have, what i want is to render parts of the map that is in the range of my camera view, My camera is focused on the player and i am interpolation it. and will this help optimize the game? or should i just render the whole map, the game is on android.